# Custmize date filter to present as from specific date to specific date using superset

Tags: apache-superset

How I can design date filter to be designed as following image
I need make special design for date filter to be present to the customer

I need the customer only choose from to date and no need to present more options

I need only present for the customer like this design

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of i want to get the final result of the date filter in superset dashboard

Comment: Don't include any opinions like this in the answer section! In the actual Comments section, you can leave a comment.